# remove/change selector value based on screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, selector

I have 1 line of code that used a selector for my parallax image

here is the code

```
<div class="expertise-top" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="images/expertise/expertise-head.jpg">
  <div class="container">
    <section>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h3>Interactive & Identity</h3>
          <p><b>ECTECIANT</b> IS MADE UP OF <b>A NETWORK OF FREELANCERS.</b> OUTSTANDING <b>CREATIVE DIRECTORS, ART DIRECTORS, WEB DESIGNERS, DEVELOPERS AND ILLUSTRATORS</b> THAT ARE ABLE TO BRING TO OUR PROJECTS THE <b>PERSONALITY</b> AND <b>QUALITY</b> THAT SETS US APART.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

the selector is

> data-image-src="images/expertise/expertise-head.jpg"

the problem is the image is not responsive, the selector acts like

> background-image

in css

So, I'm trying to change the selector src for the image based on the screen size

I know there is a way to get class or id in javascript by using getelementbyid, but is there a way to get the custom selector?

Comment: did you use background-size after your background-image attribute in your css ?

Comment: use `$(".expertise-top").attr("data-image-src","yourValue")` and set value.